# Covariance matrix for number of powers in a word

Tags: pr.probability, combinatorics-on-words

A word over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ of length $n$ may contain squares, cubes, and generally $k$th powers, where $2\le k\le n$. Let $O_k(w)$ denote the number of $k$th power occurrences in the word $w$.

> For instance, $w:=000101$ contains three square occurrences (two occurrences of 00 and one occurrence of 0101), and one cube (000). So $O_2(w)=3$ and $O_3(w)=1$.

If $w$ is selected uniformly randomly from among all words of length $n$, we may ask about the covariance matrix $\Sigma_n$ of the random variables $O_k$, $2\le k\le n$.

For $n\le 4$ I got the following (symmetric) matrices:
$$
\Sigma_2 = \frac14\left(\begin{matrix} 1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
\Sigma_3 = \frac1{16}\left(\begin{matrix} 8 & 4 \\ . & 3\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
\Sigma_4 = \frac1{64}\left(\begin{matrix} 60&40&18\\ . & 32 & 12 \\ .& .& 7\end{matrix}\right)
$$
At this point I am wondering: **can we assert that the entries of $\Sigma_n$ are rather small** compared to the means $\mathbb E(O_k)$ (which I calculated in an answer to [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160202/powers-in-strings/160216#160216))?

Intuitively it seems the answer must be yes: most of the contribution to $O_k$ comes from short subwords, and the number of such powers is almost a sum of independent random variables. Perhaps the multivariate Chebyshev applies?

Comment: I would be reasonably confident the answer is yes. I would look in the book "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer. A possibly similar problem arises there when considering the number of $k$-cliques in a random graph. These are not strictly independent, but you can get bounds on the dependence.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas thanks for the vote of confidence (and reference)